# Show "Successfully Sent" in popup or new page?

Tags: mobile-web, popup, messagebox

If the user submit a complain, and I want to inform him you are done; by this message:

> Your complain has been successfully sent
>
> Complain id: "12547786210"

**what is the best solution to show this message?**

in **pop-up** or in **new page** ?

***Hint***: The client said that pop-up is not the best practice in mobile/responsive

Answer (score 3):

**You might want to try out Toast Message**

It is a small message that shows up in a box at the bottom of the screen and disappears on its own after a few seconds. It's a simple feedback about an operation in which current activity remains visible and interactive. It basically is to inform the user of something that is not critical and that does not require specific attention and does not prevent the user from using the app device.

[image: toast-vs-popup]

[image: toast]

For example: on Gmail when a mail is sent you receive feedback of “Sending message…” written in the form of toast message.

> - For great usability, you could display the "Success Message" with the help of a toast message.
> - And navigate to the next page to display the Complaint ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "snackbar" in order to show small messages about the status of the complaint, however it should not contains too much information.

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation in a small popup at the base of the screen on mobile and at the lower left on desktop. They are above all over elements on screen, including the FAB.

You can also add a link to a page describing in details your complain information.

For more information about best practice about snackbar see [Material design snackbar page](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html#usage)

If you need a more prominent display, Material Design suggests to use the [Banner component](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html#usage)

> A banner displays an important, succinct message, and provides actions for users to address (or dismiss the banner). It requires a user action to be dismissed.
>
> Banners should be displayed at the top of the screen, below a top app bar. They are persistent and nonmodal, allowing the user to either ignore them or interact with them at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this will depend on the action itself and how long the process might take before completion.

- Does the product already have some sort of alerting channel on which the user will expect to receive info?

If so, you might want to use that.

- Is the user blocked until the process completes?

If so, replacing the page with a message page might be fine; better, you might return them to the most useful page and pop a message panel or toast (as mentioned above) above that page.

- Will the process of sending take more than a few seconds?

If so, letting the user continue their work as the submission process happens would be good citizenship; then you could "toast" them upon completion without interrupting their flow. Either way should work in mobile or desktop format.